# How do I refer to another outer function's argument?

Tags: perl, function, cgi

I have this code:

```
    for_each($products, sub {
        div({-class => 'product'},
            only_if(is_admin(), sub {
                a({-href => 'remove_product.cgi?id='.$_[0]->{'product_id'}}, 'Bla bla bla')
            }),
            img({
                -src => $_[0]->{'picture'},
                -alt => $_[0]->{'description'}
            }),
            ...
```

It's just the relevant piece. `only_if` is a function that takes a boolean and another function and executes the function only if the boolean is `true`; but that's irrelevant.

The problem is that in `$_[0]->{'product_id'}` it is trying to fetch the first argument of the function passed to `only_if`, not the "main" function (outermost).

What would be the cleanest way to refer to the outer function argument instead?

I tried with:

```
    for_each($products, sub {
        div({-class => 'product'},
            my $curr = $_[0],
            only_if(is_admin(), sub {
                a({-href => 'remove_product.cgi?id='.$curr->{'product_id'}}, 'Rimuovi prodotto')
            }),
            img({
                -src => $_[0]->{'picture'},
                -alt => $_[0]->{'description'}
            }),
```

but apparently:

> Global symbol "$curr" requires explicit package name

(on line `$curr->{'product_id'}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `$curr` is visible after `div()` call (second argument), so clearly you want to declare it before of it,

```
for_each($products, sub {
    my $curr = $_[0];
    div({-class => 'product'}, ...
```